# How to make a regex for capturing one symbol only, but with restrictions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for javascript that allows me to select a single character with a restriction: that it does NOT have a specified character besides itself.

I need to select the character `/`
but only if it does NOT have the character `a` besides it.

E.g.:

```
str = "I Like this/ and a/ basketball is round a/a ups.Papa/ tol/d /me tha/t";

myregex = ????
var patt = new RegExp(myregex);
var res = patt.split(str);
```

And the result should be something like this:

```
res[0] = "I Like this"
res[1] = " and a/ basketball is round a/a ups.Papa/ tol"
res[2] = "d "
res[3] = "me tha/t"
```

The regex should be something like:
`(if a then not)(\/)(if a then not)`

I have no idea how to do it, I tried: `[^a](\/)[^a]`, but then it selects also the characters that are beside the `/`, like `s/`, `l/d`, not the `a`'s; I don't want to select the characters beside the `/`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ have fun.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Lookbehind is working in Opera as well, so Firefox should soon follow. Actually, this functionality finally made it into ECMAScript proposal. You can read more about that in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now it seems not possible to do it with regex in JavaScript as lookbehind is not implemented in all browsers.
Partial solution would be `/\/(?!a)/g`, this will match any `/` which is not followed by `a`.
Full solution, with lookbehind, if this will get someday implemented in all major browser engines, would need the part from gurvinder372's answer, which gives us: `/(?<!a)\/(?!a)/g`

---

EDIT:
It seems, like this should be soon available in other browsers as well.
TC39, responsible for ECMAScript specification, pushed proposal for insertion of RegEx lookbehind to stage 4 - finished on 24th (with some changes on 26th) of January. [Here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) you can find some information about it and [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) you can check current browser support. At the moment of writing, only Chrome/Opera tandem (same engine) supports lookbehind.

As for "when" will be this "soon" - I don't know much about Safari and iOS browser release roadmaps, but in case of Firefox, the current highest numbered verison, which is Firefox 60 (Nightly), does not support that feature. In may F60 will become the next ESR (Extended Support Release). If you care about ESR more than just "always the freshiest", probably you will have to wait about a year more, for next ESR. At this point probably is should be already implemented.

---

EDIT2:

2 years passed, time for update. In [Firefox 78](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/78.0/releasenotes/), released on June 30, 2020, lookbehind regex is finally implemented. What's more it is an ESR release.
According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind), of the main browsers, only Safari still does not support this feature.

Answer (score 5):

Split by `/(?<!a)\//g`

```js
var output = "I Like this/ and a/ basketball is round a/a ups.Papa/ tol/d /me tha/t".split(/(?<!a)\//g);
console.log(output);
```

**Explanation**

- `/(?<!a)\/` matches `/` which is not preceded by `a`

**Note**

- Works on chrome, doesn't work on FF as suggested by @SoulReaver in his comments.

**Edit**

Or alternatively, you can just split by `/`

```js
var output = "I Like this/ and a/ basketball is round a/a ups.Papa/ tol/d /me tha/t".split(/\//g);
output = output.reduce( function(a,c){
  var lastItem = a.slice(-1)[0];
  //console.log(lastItem)
  if ( lastItem && lastItem.slice(-1) == "a" )
  {
     a.pop();
     a.push(lastItem.concat("/").concat(c));
  }
  else
  {
     a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, [])
console.log(output);
```

**Edit 2**

If `a` has to be ignored on either sides of `/`, then use the previous answer (based on reduce), just **add the look-ahead in `split`**

```
var output = "I Like this/ and a/ basketball is round a/a ups.Papa/ tol/d /me tha/t".split(/\/(?!=a)/g);
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but JS does not support lookbehind.

Comment: @SoulReaver I have shared a demo as well.

Comment: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 99
} - maybe I need newer browser here :P

Comment: @SoulReaver It works on my chrome, which browser are you testing with?

Comment: FF52 (last for XP), now checked this with FF57.0.4 on Win10, same result

Comment: sorry man, I am using chrome and I just tried it on my code, and it throws this exeption: Module parse failed: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!a)\//:

Comment: but it works on the site https://regex101.com/, but on this site https://regexr.com/, it does not

Comment: @gurvinder372 Chrome is afaik the only browser that supports lookbehinds in JS. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features

Comment: @babo221 which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Chrome is my default browser, but i need this to work on all browsers

Comment: Btw, I just found out, that it catches the /a, your code just works only if a is in front of the /

Comment: then add lookahead (this is implemented in JS already :) ). The actual problem here is the lookbehind, which is not, or at least is not implemented in all browsers yet. I am not sure about the JS actual standard, if it has lookbehind defined or not.

Comment: @babo221 I have given an alternative answer as well.

Comment: ah I see, does it work as well for the /a problem? and can u explain the code to me pls

Comment: @babo221 you mean `a` on either sides has to be ignored? Did your original question had this requirement?

Comment: `(?!=a)` should probably be `(?!a)` in the last paragraph.